# Exception message in code using .jar library in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I've a problem with my project in IntelliJ IDEA IDE and GlassFish 4.1. 
I wrote a lots of code. This code uses json.org library. Of course I downloaded it as .jar file.

I put it into project's *lib* folder. Next, I in IntelliJ I found it, I clicked right mouse button, I chose *"Add as library"*.

The project can be compiled, but when I execute a piece of code with

```
new JSONObject("...")
```

I get an error message:

> Unhandled exception in endpoint Endpoint.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Artifact configuration ("Project Structure" icon on the top right).

Then go the Libraries section and make sure the JSON jar is there.

Then go the Artifacts section and make sure you are adding the library into the artifact.

Artifact is just a fancy word for your build, it could be a JAR, EAR, whatever you are putting into the Glassfish server